# How to do live updates on an android app

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I am new at programming and developing apps so go easy on me please. Basically I want to be able to update some text every so often without having to update the entire app. I'm not sure how to go about this. Any feed back would be nice

Edit: I should have mentioned what I'm doing. I making an app for my pool, and a feature I want to add will allow people to see how many people are in the pool before they deiced to come. So I would need to constantly change my text in a certain part of my app.

Comment: You should read up on [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)s.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you want some text in the app (such as a list of items, or a paragraph somewhere in your app) that you can update without releasing a new APK?

If so, then you will need to implement some sort of client-server model in which the app checks your sever for the correct text to display.

You cannot simply update text that is coded into the app (or set in strings.xml), as all of that data is compiled into the APK.

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question I believe. Now I need to go try it out.

Comment: You may want to try out Google's AppEngine. 
There is a guide on syncing with AppEngine at http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/aesync.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a server (a couple of codes in php would suffice) where to store the lines of text you want to display in your application.

The application (which is the client in this scenario) must then call the server and ask it the line to display.

You should google for "android client server". Don't worry it's a quite easy issue.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it might be something like this but I wasn't sure. Also if you could recommend a tut or something that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just adding to this: if creating a socket server is too much, you could simplify it with regular queries to a PHP file (in a separate thread), which would then query the database, and send you back the result, which you could then update the TextView (from the UI thread, of course) with. This would probably be the easiest approach for you, especially since it doesn't sound like you're sending too much data and definitely don't require a constant socket connection